# xCode ios5: How to fade out a label text after an interval?

Tags: xcode, ios5, uilabel

I have a little iOS5 app that shows images. I click on the image to show its information. I'd like the information to fade away after a few seconds. Is there a good method to do this?

I can always implement another button action but this would be neater..

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use either `NSTimer` or `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay`. Both methods require you to call a separate method that will actually do the fading out which should be fairly straightforward.

### Example:

**NSTimer**

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(fadeOutLabels:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

**performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:**

```
/* starts the animation after 3 seconds */
[self performSelector:@selector(fadeOutLabels) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0f];
```

And you will call the method `fadeOutLabels` *(or whatever you want to call it)*

```
-(void)fadeOutLabels
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 
                          delay:0.0  /* do not add a delay because we will use performSelector. */
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut 
                     animations:^ {
                         myLabel1.alpha = 0.0;
                         myLabel2.alpha = 0.0;
                     } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [myLabel1 removeFromSuperview];
                         [myLabel2 removeFromSuperview];
                     }];
}
```

Or you can use the animation block to do all of the work:

```
-(void)fadeOutLabels
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 
                          delay:3.0  /* starts the animation after 3 seconds */
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut 
                     animations:^ {
                         myLabel1.alpha = 0.0;
                         myLabel2.alpha = 0.0;
                     } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [myLabel1 removeFromSuperview];
                         [myLabel2 removeFromSuperview];
                     }];
}
```

Comment: this works beautifully, with one issue. It works for the first image. But the label is not restored with subsequent images. Apologies for being dense.. it's been a long life :)

Comment: I thought I should add for others - I used the animation block method,  took out the removeFromSuperview statements, and set myLabel.alpha back to 1.0 before before the image id was tapped..

Comment: Agree, great answer. Code blocks... gotta love them.

Comment: If you get a warning for enumeration type 'enum UIViewAnimationCurve' , change it to 'UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut'