# didSelectRowAtIndexPath to assign values

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm having problems with a , I guess, simple thing.
I have a (It is NOT a SplitViewController) ViewController with a TableView object in it.
I want that when the users click a row in a table, my label on the right side change appropriately.

[image: My screen - ViewController with a TableView. It is NOT a SplitViewController]

My label (with the text "Nome do Vinho" on the right) that i want to change

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *rotuloDetalhesLabel;
```

I populate the TableView with this code.
I create the objects on viewDidLoad method and put in a NSArray called "vinhos".

```
// Create object 
Vinho *vinho1 = [Vinho new];
vinho1.rotulo = @"Adega de Borda Premium";

Vinho *vinho2 = [Vinho new];
vinho2.rotulo = @"Adega de Borda Premium 2";


// Populate the NSArray with the objects that I create before
vinhos = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: vinho1, vinho2, nil];
```

Populating the TableView

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Configura a Cell
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell";
    TableCell *cell = (TableCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[TableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Vinho *vinho = [vinhos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // rotuloLabel is the Label of the row
    cell.rotuloLabel.text  = vinho.rotulo;

    return cell;
}
```

I guess that it is made on didSelectRowAtIndexPath method but I dont know how.
If I forget to post something important just tell me.

Comment: Could you please post your `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you wan't to change the label on the right to the cell text?

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Vinho *vinho = [vinhos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *cellRotuloText = vinho.rotulo;
    rotuloDetalhesLabel.text = cellRotuloText;
}
```

If you wan't the fade animation as you said in the comment, maybe this could get you started: [xCode ios5: How to fade out a label text after an interval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097068/xcode-ios5-how-to-fade-out-a-label-text-after-an-interval)

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan works perfect.
By the away, there is a way to change the text with some effect? Maybe a fade in or something?

Comment: See my EDIT, update you question as well for future use of this question. If you like my answer, please up vote and accept it.